# jQuery BBQ with next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

How would one go about applying jQuery BBQ links to a page that doesn't use numbered tabs, but instead uses previous and next buttons to change the corresponding content areas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this before asking? I see that you are new to the site, so a quick tip: people here usually like to see that you have spent some time making an attempt before they spend their own time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific but basically the `previous` and `next` buttons would just need to change `window.location.hash` and the following function would pick up that change:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {   
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // deal with the hash here
});

$(window).hashchange();
```